# use panGestureRecognizer or touch events to drag and move an item ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am moving items in the view by touching them to the place where i leave it 
i am using touch events 
`touchesBegin` , `touchesMoved` , `touchesEnd`
and in `touchesMoved` i move the item.frame to the new location and it works with me
but then i found a code that use `panGestureRecognizer`
and then i cant determine what to use

the code to handle pan was

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
  if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.superview];
    CGPoint translatedCenter = CGPointMake(self.center.x + translation.x, self.center.y + translation.y);
    [self setCenter:translatedCenter];
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self];

  }
```

**given that i need the exact coordinates of the point i am touching**

Comment: Why are you changing if you have something that works and exactly matches your requirement?

Comment: i want to do the best practice , besides , when i rotate the Item it goes nuts and i only could manage to move it's center to the new location , so whenever i touch it it goes to it's center , can't manage it's offset when rotate it because if i rotate it 180 degrees , it still uses the touch location of it's original state

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is OK but seems to be running in a custom subclass of `UIView` (from references to `self`). Ideally a `UIView` should not be handling this it should be dealt with in the **View Controller** to adhere to the [**MVC**](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/a-beginners-guide-to-design-patterns--net-12752) design pattern.

Something like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIView) NSArray<UIView *> *touchableViews;

@property (nonatomic, weak) UIView *currentMovingView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark - Lifecyle

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (!self.pan) {
        self.pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didPan:)];
    }
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.pan];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.pan];
}

#pragma mark - Gestures

- (void)didPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    switch (gesture.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        {
            CGPoint loc = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
            self.currentMovingView = [self viewForLocation:loc];
        }
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        {
            if (self.currentMovingView == nil) {
                return;
            }

            self.currentMovingView.center = [gesture locationInView:self.view];
        }
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        {
            self.currentMovingView = nil;
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (UIView *)viewForLocation:(CGPoint)loc
{
    for (UIView *v in self.touchableViews) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(v.frame, loc)) {
            return v;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```

Bear in mind that this is untested code and will almost certainly need to be tweaked for different use cases but this is neat and follows good practices.

> i found a code that use panGestureRecognizer
>   and then i cant determine what to use

Unless you need something than cannot be achieved with `UIPanGestureRecogniser`, **use it**.